# gradle:how to speed up the looking up the maven repository for a dependency?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

My project has more than 10+ maven repositories in the build.gradle, and the denpendencies speicified in my projoect are about 100 or more. This causes a problem. Each time I sync the gradle, it would try each maven repository for each dependency until it finds one providing that module.

The gradle [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html#N10621) contain the following:

> A project can have multiple repositories. Gradle will look for a dependency in each repository in the order they are specified, stopping at the first repository that contains the requested module.

However, this is really time-consuming. How can I speed up this process? Can I give some hint for a denpendency using some repository, avoid trying each one blindly?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way around this. But it shouldn't take long unless a large amount has new updates/needs to be downloaded. Gradle scans through each, check if it's available and continues. I also have a lot of repositories in one of my project but the build  doesn't take long at all.

Comment: Yes. I think the reason why it takes so long maybe sometimes some repository server take long to response. I have met this sevral times. Maybe a server issue